# MethodChannel dont Work when release in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-method-channel

****MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method****

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTEeU.png) (the same code works when it is debug)

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val channelName = "Toast" ;

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        var channel  = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger , channelName);

        channel.setMethodCallHandler{call , result-> if(call.method=="showToast"){
           
            Toast.makeText(this , "toast" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the app running on your Editor and run the this command **Flutter clear**, then run **flutter pub get** to get all dependencies again and run the app on your device it will work.